# query update sqlite3 with flask

Tags: python, sqlite

Can anyone advise me how to pass input text from **edit.html** to **views.py** app.route? I am stuck there and I am trying to learn more flask.

**templates/edit.html**

```
 <form action="{{ url_for('update_entry', update_id=row['id']) }}"method="post">
 <input type = "text"  name="update_id" value="{{row["id"]}}" />
 <input type = "text" name="nm" value="{{row["name"]}}"  />
 <input type = "text" name="city" value="{{row["city"]}}" />
 <input type = "text" name="pin" value="{{row["pin"]}}"   /> 
 <input type="Submit" value="Update">
```

**views.py**

```
@app.route('/update/<int:update_id>',  methods=['POST'])
def update_entry(update_id):
   nm = request.form['nm']
   addr = request.form['add']
   city = request.form['city']
   pin = request.form['pin']
   con = sql.connect("database.db")
   con.row_factory = sql.Row
   cur = con.cursor()
   update_id=int(update_id)
   cur.execute("update students set name=?, addr=?, city=?, pin=? where id=?", (nm, addr, city, pin, update_id,))
   con.commit()
   rows = cur.fetchall();
   return redirect("http://192.168.1.1:4000/list")
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: use form submit or ajax submit  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flask/flask_sending_form_data_to_template.htm

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, I've modified the code, now is working.